# PHP - Echo Array error

Tags: php, sql, arrays, row, echo

```html
<?php

if (isset($_GET['id']) && filter_var($_GET['id'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) {
    $id=$_GET['id'];
}else{
  header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
  exit("<h1>Not Found</h1>\n<p>The submitted data is not valid.</p>");
}



$query = "SELECT * FROM all_parks WHERE id = $id";


$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die ("Error querying database.");


$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  $state = $row['state'];
  $type = $row['type'];
  $name = $row['name'];
  $short_intro = $row['short_intro'];
  $long_description = $row['long_description'];
  $parkimage = $row['image_url'];
  $allowed = $row['allowed'];
  $not_allowed = $row['not_allowed'];
  $warnings = $row['warnings'];
  $more_details = $row['more_details'];
  $neighboring_parks = ['neighboring_parks'];
  $website = ['website'];
  $camping = ['camping'];
  $hiking = ['hiking'];
  $volunteer = ['volunteer'];
  $map = ['google_map_location'];
  $telephone = ['telephone'];
  $email = ['email'];

?>
```

$map, $website, $camping, $hiking is giving a 404 error for the link

$parkimage is not showing

$volunteer, $donate, $neighboring_parks is echoing 'Array' on the page

Comment: Please add also some explanation

Comment: add $row to this array variable  $website = ['website'];
  $camping = ['camping'];
  $hiking = ['hiking'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot to write $row , Use this code-

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['id']) && filter_var($_GET['id'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) {
    $id=$_GET['id'];
}else{
  header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
  exit("<h1>Not Found</h1>\n<p>The submitted data is not valid.</p>");
}



$query = "SELECT * FROM all_parks WHERE id = $id";


$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die ("Error querying database.");


$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  $state = $row['state'];
  $type = $row['type'];
  $name = $row['name'];
  $short_intro = $row['short_intro'];
  $long_description = $row['long_description'];
  $parkimage = $row['image_url'];
  $allowed = $row['allowed'];
  $not_allowed = $row['not_allowed'];
  $warnings = $row['warnings'];
  $more_details = $row['more_details'];
  $neighboring_parks = $row['neighboring_parks'];
  $website = $row['website'];
  $camping = $row['camping'];
  $hiking = $row['hiking'];
  $volunteer = $row['volunteer'];
  $map = $row['google_map_location'];
  $telephone = $row['telephone'];
  $email = $row['email'];

?>
```

It Will Work.

Answer (score -1):

Use `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))`, it will work.